# Javascript: Change Border color on Image Element?

Tags: javascript

In my javascript code, I'm looking to target the image element after the first image is hidden to show a green border? The code seems to run with no error output? What am I missing?

Here is the html:

```
<img src="black_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="profile_pic"></img>
    <img src="white_cat.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="next_profile"></img>
    <img src="" alt="Swipe Left" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_left" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile(); update_pic('swipe_left');"></img>
    <img src="" alt="Swipe Right" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_right" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile(); update_pic();"></img>
    <p id="display_message"></p>
```

This is javascript code:

```
function hide_profile() {
        document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

function show_profile() {
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.display = "none";
}

function update_pic(id) {
    if (id == 'swipe_left') {
        document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You didn\'t Like this Cat!";
        document.getElementById("next_profile").style.borderColor = "green";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You Liked this Cat!";
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI images are self-closing `<img />`. There is no `</img>`

Comment: Does the border have a width to begin with?

Comment: @j08691 Actually, closing all the tags is valid XHTML ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you assigned a color but not a size. You can set the color, size, and style at the same time using the `border` property.

```js
function hide_profile() {
  document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function show_profile() {
  document.getElementById("next_profile").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("next_profile").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.display = "none";
}

function update_pic(id) {
  if (id == 'swipe_left') {
    document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You didn\'t Like this Cat!";
    document.getElementById('next_profile').style.border = 'solid 1px green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You Liked this Cat!";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="profile_pic"></img>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/300/300" alt="Profile Pic" height="300" width="300" id="next_profile" />
<img src="" alt="Swipe Left" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_left" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile(); update_pic('swipe_left');" />
<img src="" alt="Swipe Right" height="150" width="150" id="swipe_right" onclick="hide_profile(); show_profile(); update_pic();" />
<p id="display_message"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the other border styles including width and style

```
function hide_profile() {
        document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

function show_profile() {
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("next_profile").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("profile_pic").style.display = "none";
}

function update_pic(id) {
    if (id == 'swipe_left') {
        document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You didn\'t Like this Cat!";

        // look here!
        document.getElementById("next_profile").style.border = "1px solid green";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = "You Liked this Cat!";
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmpts000/